# Stuck trying to input into string from text file

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that allows you to parse a text file for usernames and passwords and then run them against a database to return their firstname, lastname and department name. I have gotten the program to parse a textfile line by line and I've created and if else statement to check if that line contains "[email]" or "[password]". What I'm trying to do is if the line contains one of those, copy the entire line into a string that I can work with.
This is my code so far, which I admit is not the best, as I am still learning.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace trevorsenior
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["trevorsenior.Properties.Settings.trevordatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void parsetextfile()
    {
        string filepath = string.Format(textBox1.Text);
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filepath))
        {
            if (line.Contains("[email]")||line.Contains("[password]"))
            {
                string email2="msue0001";
                string password2;
                password2 = "msuepassword";
                populateusername(email2, password2);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                sum++;
            }
        }
        if (sum>0&&count==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no usernames or passwords in this file");
        }
    }
    private void populateusername(string email2, string password2)
    {
        string usernamein = email2;
        string passwordin = password2;
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE username='" + usernamein + "' AND password='" + passwordin + "'");
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            DataTable userstable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(userstable);
            lister.DisplayMember = "firstname";
            lister.ValueMember = "userId";
            lister.DataSource = userstable;
        }
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            DataTable userstable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(userstable);
            lister2.DisplayMember = "lastname";
            lister2.ValueMember = "userId";
            lister2.DataSource = userstable;
        }
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            DataTable userstable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(userstable);
            lister3.DisplayMember = "deptname";
            lister3.ValueMember = "userId";
            lister3.DataSource = userstable;
        }
    }

    private void lister_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //populateusername();
        parsetextfile();
    }

    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Open Phishing Textfile";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.Filter = "TXT files| *.txt";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the text file ive been trying to parse:

```
Array
(

[lsd] => AVp4gWh_

[display] => 

[enable_profile_selector] => 

[isprivate] => 

[legacy_return] => 1

[profile_selector_ids] => 

[skip_api_login] => 

[signed_next] => 

[trynum] => 1

[timezone] => 240

[lgndim] => eyJ3IjoxMDI0LCJoIjo3NjgsImF3IjoxMDI0LCJhaCI6NzQxLCJjIjoyNH0=

[lgnrnd] => 170514_OoLu

[lgnjs] => 1460333318

[email] => jsmith0001

[pass] => jpassword

[persistent] => 

[default_persistent] => 1

[qsstamp] => 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

)


Array
(

[lsd] => AVp4gWh_

[display] => 

[enable_profile_selector] => 

[isprivate] => 

[legacy_return] => 1

[profile_selector_ids] => 

[skip_api_login] => 

[signed_next] => 

[trynum] => 1

[timezone] => 240

[lgndim] => eyJ3IjoxMDI0LCJoIjo3NjgsImF3IjoxMDI0LCJhaCI6NzQxLCJjIjoyNH0=

[lgnrnd] => 170514_OoLu

[lgnjs] => 1460333337

[email] => msue0001

[pass] => mspassword

[persistent] => 

[default_persistent] => 1

[qsstamp] => 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

)
```

Does anyone know if this can be done? I apologize if I don't make much sense, I'm fairly new to c#

Comment: I assume that your program is not working. Can you be more specific about which part that is not working?

Comment: Well firstly, I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but you're missing a closing curly bracket on you `public Form_1` method...

Comment: move `DataTable userstable = new DataTable();` to class scope. and move the 3 lines after `Fill` to Form load.

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell you've already accomplished your goal. [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array of strings, one string for each line. So at this point in your code...

```
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filepath))
        {
            if (line.Contains("[email]") || line.Contains("[password]"))
            {
                // ** RIGHT HERE, BABY **
```

`line` is exactly what you want: a string containing the entire line from the file for you to "work with".